# Discord bot sending a MP4 converted to MP3 file in discord chat

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I've made a discord bot which sends extracts audio from a youtube video via youtube-dl and sends it into the chat. When it extracts the audio though, it uses ffmpeg to convert it into mp3 and finally the code searches the file in my current directory (as there the file is downloaded to) but cannot find it.

After doing many things i made some code which downloaded and then searched the file
heres the code:

Finder File:

```
def find(file):
    for root,dirs,files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
        for filename in files:
            if filename == file:
                return os.path.join(root,file)
```

Main File:

```
@bot.command(description = "Downloads songs from youtube and sends it")
async def youtube_song(ctx,url):
    await ctx.send("Starting... __[MIGHT TAKE A MINUTE]__")
    run(f'youtube-dl -x --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 --output %(title)s.%(ext)s {url}')
    s = check_call(f'youtube-dl --get-filename {url}' + '.mp3') 
    g = find(s)
    await ctx.channel.send("Audio is ready.")
    with open(s,'rb') as w:
        await ctx.channel.send(file = discord.File(w))
```

It downloads and changes it successfully but heres the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\callm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 229, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\callm\Dropbox\My PC (PC1001)\Desktop\Python Files\DiscordGonk.py", line 61, in youtube_song    
    await ctx.channel.send(file = discord.File(w))

    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\callm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\file.py", line 92, in __init__ 
    raise ValueError(f'File buffer {fp!r} must be seekable and readable')
ValueError: File buffer <_io.BufferedReader name=0> must be 
seekable and readable
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres the code i made to fix the problem:

````
async def youtube_song(ctx,url):
    await ctx.send("Starting... __[MIGHT TAKE **MINUTES**]__")
    run(f'youtube-dl -x --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 --output %(title)s.%(ext)s {url}')
    filename = check_output(f'youtube-dl --get-title {url}')
    File = filename.decode('utf-8')
    File1 = File.rstrip()
    File1 += ".mp3"
    for root,dirs,files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
        for file in files:
            print(file)
            if file == File1:
                s = (os.path.join(root,File1))
                await ctx.channel.send(file = discord.File(s))
                await ctx.channel.send("Audio is ready.")```
````

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).